# Awesome WM launchbar

Tags: awesome-wm

anyone out there experienced with the awesome WM? If so here is a question:

I have a problem getting my launchbar to appear in the status bar. The setup works fine on my single monitor computer at home but at work I have a dual monitor setup  and I can't get it to appear, nada, zilch, zipp. Can't get it to show.

I have pretty much the same code from : https://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Quick_launch_bar_widget

any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I've found so far is to replace the code

```
mywibox[s].widgets = {
    {
        mylauncher,
        mytaglist[s],
        launchbar,
        mypromptbox[s],
        layout = awful.widget.layout.horizontal.rightleft
    }
    mylayoutbox[s],
    ...
}
```

by something more archaic:

```
mainwidgets = { mylauncher, mytaglist[s] }
for i = 1, table.getn(launchbar) do table.insert(mainwidgets, launchbar[i]) end
table.insert(mainwidgets, mypromptbox[s])
mainwidgets.layout = awful.widget.layout.horizontal.rightleft
mywibox[s].widgets = {
    mainwidgets,
    mylayoutbox[s],
    ...
}
```

but I guess there must be a much more elegant solution for this...?

[edit]

actually there is one more elegant solution:

just replace

```
...
launchbar,
...
```

by

```
...
s == 1 and launchbar or nil,
...
```

in the original code, if it is sufficient to have the quicklaunch icons on the main screen only

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried that and it still didn't work for me. I tried both solutions too. For some reason the same setup is ignoring launchbar. But I can add textbox separators no problem :-/ I'm a total loss as to why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

As of git/master version of Awesome the widget works well for two monitors. You might try building Awesome from repository and trying the launchbar again if you are still interested.